# What are all the twin primes $p$ and $q = p + 2$ for which $pq - 2$ is also prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

It seems that $p = 3$ and $q = 5$ ($pq - 2 = 13$) are the only solutions. However I'm having a difficult time proving this.

I have that all primes can be represented as $3k + 1$ or $3k + 2$ so if $p = 3k + 2$ then $q = 3k + 4$ and 
\begin{align*}
  pq - 2 &= (3k + 2)(3k + 4) - 2\\
     &= 9k^2 + 18k + 8 - 2\\
     &= 9k^2 + 18k + 6\\
     &= 3(3k^2 + 6k + 2) \text{             which can't be prime}
\end{align*}

So that seems promising. But when I let $p = 3k + 1$ and $q = 3k + 3$ I get

\begin{align*}
pq -2 &= (3k + 1)(3k + 3) - 2\\
&= 9k^2 + 12k + 3 - 1\\
&= 9k^2 + 12k + 2,
\end{align*}

which could very well be prime. So what do I do? It appears, though, that the only solution is $p = 3$.

Comment: If $q = 3k+3$, then $q$ isn't prime (unless $k = 0$).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We notice that for $p=3$ and $q=5$ we have a solution. 
Let $p \geq 5$

Then p has form $p=6k \pm 1$ where $k \in N$

If $p=6k+1$ then $q=6k+3=3(2k+1)$ so $q$ is not a prime then. That leaves us with $p=6k-1$. Then $q=6k+1$ so $pq-2=(6k-1)(6k+1)-2=36k^2-3=3(12k^2-1)$ which is not a prime.

We conclude that there is no solution for $p \geq 5$ so the only solution is $p,q (3,5)$

Comment: Duh! I never thought to think of $q$... Only $pq - 2$.

Comment: Why did you chose to express the primes $p \ge 5$ as 6k+1 and 6k-1 instead of say, 4k+1 and 4k-1 or other form? Is it for the convenience to show $pq -2 $ isn't a prime? Or do we need it to be $6k+1$ and $6k-1$ to express the primes greater than or equal to 5?

Comment: @alu because with 4k +-1, for k = 1, you get primes 3 and 5 and 3 is not greater or equal to 5 :)

Comment: @mateeeeeee Nice :) Also I thought about it and I see if we take $4k+-1$ , we can't have 3 common to show it's divisible by 3. If we take $3k+-1$ and say k=2, 3,...,n, then it's basically $6k+-1$. But I wonder if I will be able to express primes in a way that will help me to prove the statement if I'm given a different problem. I probably wouldn't know if I should express it like $5k+1, 5k+2...$ or $8k+1, 8k+3...$ etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\,\ {\rm mod\ 3}\!:\ p\not\equiv \color{#c00}0\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#0a0}q\,(pq\!-\!2) = \overbrace{(p\,+\,2)}^{\large 0\ {\rm  if}\ p\,\equiv\,\color{#c00}{\bf 1}\ }\,\overbrace{(p\,(p+2)-2)}^{\large\ 0\ {\rm if}\ p\,\equiv\,\color{#c00} 2}\equiv 0 $

hence we conclude  $\ 3\nmid \color{#0a0}q\,\Rightarrow\,3\mid pq-2$